# What is the difference between 诡异 and 奇诡?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, usage, difference

According to Google Translate it is "Strange" and "Strangeness"

But I saw a native speaker post "好诡异", which would be "how strangeness?"

When would you use one or the other?

Comment: 应用汉语词典：诡异：（形）奇异；怪异：言辞～。奇诡 not in this dictionary nor 现代汉语词典 （奇怪 in both, more common word for "strange") but find 2 example sentences for 奇诡 in each of iciba and jukuu), maybe 奇诡 has come into use more recently, anyhow both apparently more emphatic than than 奇怪)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both **诡异** and **奇诡** are adjectives. The "strangeness" translation is incorrect.

**诡异** is a commonly used word meaning **"strange"**. It can be used both colloquially and in writing. The idiom **"好诡异"** you mentioned means "How strange it is!".

**奇诡** is a formal word used exclusively in literatures. It is a stronger form of **诡异** and is usually reserved for things that are extremely bizarre or supernatural. Use this word with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Both "诡异" and "奇诡" means strange or something out of the the ordinary, its a move elaborate expression than "奇怪", "奇异", "怪异"。

"好诡异" can translate to "how strange" or even better "so out of the ordinary".